# AWS Lambda connected to Private VPC cannot start/stop EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have created AWS Lambda to start and stop EC2 instances hosted in private VPC.

I could deploy the Lambda function in 'NO VPC' and perform action without any issues.

But when I deploy the Lambda function in the private VPC (where my EC2 is located) and 2 different subnets (in one of those subnet EC2 is launched) with necessary security group changes, I got **timed out error** and could not perform actions anymore.

**Question:** Is it necessary to add a NAT Gateway to Lambda, though there is no requirement of outer internet?

If yes, please let me know why.

If no, please let me know what else I have to check to get this process working.

Comment: How are you actually starting and stopping the ec2 instances?

Answer (score 3):

When making an API call to AWS, the [service endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) are accessible from the Internet. Therefore, issuing a command to Start or Stop an Amazon EC2 instance requires access to the Internet.

If an AWS Lambda function is *not* configured to use a VPC, then it has **access to the Internet by default**.

If an AWS Lambda function is configured to use a VPC, and that Lambda function needs to access the Internet, then:

- Configure the Lambda function to use a **private subnet**
- Launch a **NAT Gateway in a public subnet** and update the private subnet Route Tables to use the NAT Gateway for Internet-bound traffic

Alternatively, you could create a **VPC Endpoint for EC2**. This allows commands destined for the EC2 service to pass through the VPC Endpoint without going via the Internet. This is commonly done for VPCs that have no Internet Gateway (eg Dev/Test VPCs with no public access).

Finally, have a think about whether the Lambda function actually needs to be connected to a VPC. If it needs to access within the VPC *and* access the Internet, then you'll need to use one of the above methods. However, if it does not require access to the VPC, then do not connect it to the VPC and it will connect to the internet just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your replay .

Comment: But i have observed that my EC2 lauched in private subnet can be stopped with a lamda launched in NOVPC . Could you please explain how my EC2 accesses API call/request from the internet

Comment: API calls that are made to AWS services are made to [service endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) that exist on the Internet (eg `ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`). It does not matter where the actual EC2 instance is placed, nor whether it is accessible, because **the call is made to AWS**, not the instance itself. In response, AWS will provision/terminate the underlying resources that run the virtual machine. That is why any command to start/stop an instance must be made via the Internet.

Comment: Thank You . I have got my complete answer .